# looks like a valid python syntax to me but gives me invalid error using in django

Tags: python, django

Maybe I'm wrong but this looks like a valid python code to me but I get invalid syntax....I'm trying to split url,removing www when domain is displayed. This is my code:

```
return urlparse(urlsplit(self.url)).netloc if self.url else "be kind to one another"
```

but this is wrong...
maybe I'm approaching wrong for implementing this function..
any help would be appreciated

Edit 1: Now I get 'SplitResult' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: Is `but this is wrong...` part of your code?

Comment: opps no I meant to add that as a comment

Comment: What do you mean by "invalid syntax"? Literally a `SyntaxError`?

Comment: What you've shown us is good... it was added in python 2.5 so if have a very old linux or something, it may not be supported. Otherwise, it could be a problem with the line above (e.g., an unclosed paren). Exactly where does the syntax error point?

Comment: so... the syntax error went away? For the new problem, your paren is in the wrong place. You want to take netloc first and then urlparse `urlparse(urlsplit(self.url).netloc)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just need to delete urlsplit function from your code and it will work as expected:

```
from urlparse import urlparse
url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34446468/looks-like-a-valid-python-syntax-to-me-but-gives-me-invalid-error-using-in-djang"
long_url = urlparse(url).netloc if url else "be kind to one another"
long_url.split('.', 1)[1] if long_url.split('.', 1)[0] == 'www' else long_url
```

Comment: maybe I didn't clarify, if I put www.stackoverflow.com, I want only stackoverflow.com which is why I put urlsplit function

Comment: @haloyoba if so please check updated version, you need one more if

Comment: thank you, not only it works but I understood this code :) Happy Holidays